# Box API large file upload results in corrupt file

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to upload a large file > 200 MB using new Box API.
Can I upload it in chunks?

Comment: Are you able to upload the same file via the Box website, FTP, or webDAV?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the box API does not support uploading a file in chunks. You may include a "Content-MD5" header with your request that contains the SHA1 hash of the file. Box will check this against the uploaded contents to ensure the file is not corrupted in transit.

See: http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file